# swapping elements of a given symbolic matrices

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

So, the problem is simple to understand. Given any symbolic matrix of any dimmension I want to swap the elements in order to obtain one matrix of the same size, same elements but distributed differently.

For instance

```
syms a b c

A=[a b c;0 0 c]
```

swapping A we can get:

```
A=[b a c;0 c 0];
```

Comment: Is there any difference between `[a b;0 0]` and `[b a;0 0]` for your application? Maybe this is already sufficient: `sz=[4,4];sym('a',sz).*randi([0,1],sz);`?

Comment: @Daniel, I realized that this problem reduces to one of swapping randomically the elements of a given matrix, I'm going to edit the post, even the title.

Comment: So you got an input matrix `A` and you want to randomly permute the elements? Then you could definitely simplify your question, in this case it is irrelevant which elements are allowed or not, the matrix already exists.

Comment: @Daniel, you're right. I realized this later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `randperm(numel(A))` you can generate a random permutation of the numbers 1:numel(A), which are the indices in your matrix.

```
A(:)=A(randperm(numel(A)));
```

The `A(:)` on the left side is required to preserve the shape, otherwise you end up with a vector of the elements. If you wish to keep your matrix A unchanged:

```
B=A; %just to get a matrix of same size and datatype
B(:)=A(randperm(numel(A)));
```